# How would I call the second function to operate on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like for my 20 second timer to operate on the click of a button, alongside the 20 second alert. How would I go about doing this?

HTML

```
<aside class="start-box">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="toggleBtn" onclick="startClock();"></button>
          </aside>



/*Alerts after 20 seconds*/

var alertTimerId = 0;


function startClock () {
  setTimeout (gameOver(), 20000);
}

function gameOver ()
{
  alert("The time is up!");
}


/*Counts down the timer in the countdown box for 20 seconds*/

var secondsLeft = 20;
var interval = 
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = --secondsLeft;

  if (secondsLeft <= 0)
  {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Gotta catch em' all!";
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why do you use strings for `setTimeout`? Use `setTimeout (gameOver, 20000);`

Comment: Use `setTimeout (gameOver(), 20000); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine both of these functions into the single `setInterval`:

```js
var timer, secondsLeft;

function startClock () {
  secondsLeft = 20;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = --secondsLeft;

    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
    {
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Gotta catch em' all!";
      clearInterval(timer);
      alert('The time is up'); // alert is now here!
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<aside class="start-box">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="toggleBtn" onclick="startClock();">Start</button>
</aside>

<div id='countdown'></div>
```

Note that it will not alert, because StackOverflow does not allow `alerts` in its code snippets.

It will work in your case or here, [at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/k8yvkd3g/1/).

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. this is exactly what I was looking for. The second function didn't actually have a name, so combining it with the first function in such a way is brilliant. I'll continue to look it over to make sure I understand the changes.

Comment: I actually just changed it on my end and deleted my previous comment. Thanks again for the help.